# jquery script to animate text webkit-transform infinite hue-rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, jquery-animate, infinite-loop

I am trying to write the following in a jquery. I want the text to be animated with hue in an infinite loop.

Can anyone please help me.

```
p {
    text-indent: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.25em;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 0.7cm;
    color: #f35626;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg, #135626, #feab3a);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: hue 30s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hue {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {

@-webkit-keyframes hue {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
       -webkit-transform: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: it maybe easier if you use velocity js  -- http://julian.com/research/velocity/ -- however im not saying you should use that plugin but just as an alternative to Jquery animate as it has powerful features

Comment: what are the parameters I need to use in velocity() to achieve this? - Thanks

Comment: no you dont, however with velocity you can queue those hue rotations